# Dynamic return status from restler

Tags: restler

If I put an `@status 201` in my function comments then that's what gets returned always on success.   Is there a way to make that dynamic?

For example, I have a `putChild($child_id, $team_id)` method defined.  If the child is not already on the team, then I insert them and return a 201.  If they are already on the team though, I just don't do anything.  In that case I'd want a 200 status to go back, not a 201.

Not sure how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest version in the v3 branch, you can do the following in the api method to override the status code at runtime

```
$this->restler->responseCode = 201;
```